# How to start a python process that does not inherit a TensorFlow state?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, python-multiprocessing

I start several processes with the `multiprocessing` module:

```
    processes = [Process(name=name + str(i), target=target, args=[args])
                 for i in range(nb_processes)]

    for process in processes:
        process.start()
```

I make sure to import `tensorflow` **after** the processes are started, and build a graph.

Now each of the processes gets memory allocated on the GPU. I tried changing the start method to `spawn` and `forkserver`, but this had no effect.

So, how do I make sure that the processes from `multiprocessing` do not claim GPU memory?